# Accessing a vector from dput structure

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to iterate over a list in R and have hit a roadblock...
The goal is to write this data out to a data.frame which I will then write to an Excel spreadsheet (seems to be by and far the easiest way to create an Excel spreadsheet from R using the xlsx library) with each Tab1, Tab2, etc corresponding to a sheet in a workbook.

Using

```
dput(MyRObject,file="", control=c("useSource"))
```

in R I have a structure that looks like this (not cleaned up per an SO suggestion)....

```
list(tab1 = list(PData = c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.995, 0.24661,
0.17913, 0.13058, 0.04435, 0.579631613406504, 0.993273399970982,
1.38978824245787, 2.35062458463194), NData = c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95,
0.995, 0.75339, 0.82087, 0.86942, 0.95565, 0.579631613406505,
0.993273399970982, 1.38978824245787, 2.35062458463194)), tab2 = list(
    PData = c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.995, 0.2, 0.14286, 0.1029,
    0.03423, 0.8496, 1.28071636787584, 1.65931628110111, 2.48854182345497
    ), NData = c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.995, 0.8, 0.85714, 0.8971,
    0.96577, 0.849600000000001, 1.28071636787583, 1.65931628110111,
    2.48854182345497)), tab3 = list(PData = c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95,
0.995, 0.14286, 0.1, 0.07104, 0.02308, 1.28071636787584, 1.6896,
2.01379602569623, 2.64732002458351), NData = c(0.8, 0.9, 0.95,
0.995, 0.85714, 0.9, 0.92896, 0.97692, 1.28071636787584, 1.6896,
2.01379602569622, 2.64732002458351)))
```

I'm trying to coerce each "Tab" into a data.frame so each tab in my spreadsheet looks like this..

Tab1's worksheet would look like this after formatting the vector to 3 columns

```
PData
Sensitivity Optimal Relative
0.8         0.24661    0.57963
0.9         0.17913    0.99327
0.95        0.13058    1.3898
0.995       0.04435    2.3506      

NData
Sensitivity  Optimal   Relative
0.8          0.75339    0.57963
0.9          0.82087    0.99327
0.95         0.86942    1.3898
0.995        0.95565    2.3506
```

and so for Tab 2, Tab3...

I have gotten as far as partially iterating over it, like this......

using a function like this....

```
nametree(myListData)

nametree <- function(X, prefix = ""){
  if( is.list(X) )
    for( i in seq_along(X) ) {
      cat( prefix, names(X)[i], "\n", sep="" )
      nametree(X[[i]], paste0(prefix, "--->"))
    }
}
```

That gets me....

```
tab1
--->PData
--->NData
tab2
--->PData
--->NData
```

How do I access the vector for PData and NData from dput? I'm sure there's an easier way but my lack of R knowledge is making this difficult.

Comment: "clean[ing] up for readability" killed reproducibility. Your `dput` output gives errors.

Comment: You would be better served writing each table separately than trying to put them into a single structure to write. This would require 2 loops - an outer one for the tabs and an inner one for the tables.

Comment: like this:
 '$tab1
        Sensitivity Optimal  Relative
PData.A       0.800 0.24661 0.5796316
PData.B       0.900 0.17913 0.9932734
PData.C       0.950 0.13058 1.3897882
PData.D       0.995 0.04435 2.3506246
NData.A       0.800 0.75339 0.5796316
NData.B       0.900 0.82087 0.9932734
NData.C       0.950 0.86942 1.3897882
NData.D       0.995 0.95565 2.3506246
'

Comment: Hi guys! I figured it out using my own hint above iterating with "i". Turns out that control=c("useControl") is tremendously helpful

Comment: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=whln1j2J&version=1

Comment: WOW! germcd, that is a great example! This is more than I was hoping for and I'm very happy.